# 'React/RCTRootView.h' file not found after detach from expo

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, expo, react-native-navigation

I created a new project with [expo](https://github.com/expo/expo) and detached it.

When I try to run the iOS project in XCode, it gives an error

> 'React/RCTRootView.h' file not found

If I create a new project with `react-native init` instead, I'm able to build with [react-native-navigation](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation) successfully. Why does it fail with expo?

#### Steps to Reproduce

https://github.com/James2516/expo-native-nav

Run `npm install` and try building the iOS project in Xcode.

Or start a new project:

1. `exp init`
2. `exp detach`
3. `yarn add react-native-navigation`
4. `react-native-link`
5. `cd ios && pod install`

I have tried adding React to build target [image]